# Trying to understand ungrammaticality

Tags: grammaticality, negative-polarity-items

In which way are the sentences marked with the asterisk ungrammatical?

I didn't drink a drop.
*I drank a drop.
I never eat a bite.
*I eat a bite.
he won't do a thing.
*he will do a thing.
I don't give a damn.
*I give a damn.

Comment: All those sound grammatical to me.  Where did you get this (link?) ? Also, what do _you_ think is going on?

Comment: I got it from an article by linguist John Lawler, or Arnold Zwicky. It was about Negative Polarity Items (NPIs).

Comment: None of those are ungrammatical.

Comment: Here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjf9daBkLnmAhXX3YUKHamoAtYQFjAAegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw3PyI4GoqiqPlMrN2tSWG9y

Comment: I think you’ve misconstrued the point that article was making.

Comment: Tell me how, Jim.

Answer (score -2):

the first two are ungrammatical because of the tense and temporal aspect of the verbs.

The other two are alright, because the semantics are broader and allow for different aspects. Or because colloquial speech tends to reduction.

That means, *I eat a bite* describes a permanent state of affairs, but *a bite* specifically restricts it to a limited time span, almost a singular point in time. Therefore it should use progressive tense.

However, certain narrative styles might use present tense for simplicity throughout. I might also understand *and now we eat* as subjunctive, but this grammatical mood is largely lost on English.

read [Lexical vs. grammatical aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect#Lexical_vs._grammatical_aspect).

Comment: "OK, I drank a drop or two, Officer".

Comment: I eat a bite. Then I eat another and another. Can you picture the delight?